# Electron Framework vulnerability - Explaining remote code execution

Tags: skype, code-execution

Electron is a "web application writing platform" used by software such as Skype and Slack for Windows (among many others). [News](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/24/skype_signal_slack_nherit_electron_vuln/) [articles](https://www.cyberscoop.com/electron-vulnerability-skype-slack/) from today are purporting that these applications are now vulnerable to remote code execution due to  vulnerabilities in the Electron framework itself.

I am running Skype on my Windows machine. It registers itself as the default handler for a protocol (lets say skype://). It is not running as a service. How am I susceptible to remote code execution if the software is not running as a service? What steps would need to happen for RCE to happen... namely would I have to click on a link? Would an attacker have to initiate a skype conversation with me in order to trigger the exploit?

Further is the attack mechanism the same for every piece of software affected or is it a different attack vector for every piece of software?

---

EDIT:
Looking through the release notes and source code commits, I noticed [this change](https://github.com/electron/electron/commit/c49cb29ddf3368daf279bd60c007f9c015bc834c).

[image: Electron source code change]

It seems to imply the attack vector would be a specially crafted 'launching' uri (taking advantage of the default handler). If that's true though it makes me think the user would either have to click this link or visit a website that redirects to the link. Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-1000006) RCE is triggered when a specially crafted URL is clicked that will be handled by Electron. The vulnerability is only for Windows, and does not affect macOS or Linux. See the Electron team's [blog post](https://electronjs.org/blog/protocol-handler-fix) for more details.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to redirect to such a link (i.e. if you visit a malicious http website)?

Comment: It is possible to redirect to other protocols from http. Generally the browser and/or system would give you a warning asking you if you want to open the link, but this may depend on configuration. It would be best to test this on links that you know aren't malicious.